# Question about airmon-ng

Tags: kali-linux, airmon-ng, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

I have a question about the program aircrack.
When I want start the monitor mode in my adapter i use the command:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

and when i wanna stop the monitor mode i use the command:

```
airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

When I use the last command, my internet does not come back.  In other words, i cant see the networks to connect.

Do I need to enter with another command?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem, you should read the documentation https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng .

If you want to "activate" your network interface again, you must disable  monitor mode.

-$ airmon-ng stop wlan0mon

and

-$ service network-manager restart